# How to download and read a file from a web site without having web browser?

Tags: java, url, if-statement, file-io, while-loop

If a user don't have any web browser, which java code he should write (and which classes he needs) to download and read file? Lets say that this is the URL where the file will be downloaded:
http://www.thewebsource.serv/dir1/myfile.txt

So far I have tried to access a url, but in order to download a file what procedure I should follow.

```
package filedownload;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;


public class FileDownload {

public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

    Desktop d=Desktop.getDesktop();

    d.browse(new URI("http://www.thewebsource.serv/dir1/myfile.txt"));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this using the URL class:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

From java doc tutorials: [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html)